# Incorrect "Questions Closed" label in Question Close Stats

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

At the bottom of the Question Close Stats page of the 10k tools, there is a section called "Custom closed as off-topic questions", which shows manually typed custom reasons that were used recently. For each of these reasons, there is a counter labeled "Questions Closed", which presumably shows how many questions were closed for that reason.

Except that counter shows how many questions were voted to be closed with that custom reason, not how many questions were actually closed. This can be easily seen by checking the "Closure statistics" table, which *does* show how many questions were closed (and edited, reopened).

The entry "off-topic - Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)" shows a lower number of closed questions than the sum of all the custom reasons under "Custom closed as off-topic questions".